# Android Webkit CookieManager: How to get all cookies via CookieManager?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cookies

I'm trying to get cookies of [m.facebook.com](http://m.facebook.com) loaded in `android.webkit.WebView` via `CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie()` but it's not giving the expected results

```
myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com");

String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie("m.facebook.com");
```

I want to use `c_user` field to check whether user is logged in so I can redirect to custom URL.
Viewing cookies of http://m.facebook.com in Google Chrome shows many fields like:

`c_user
datr
fr
dnonce
m_pixel_ratio
sb
wd
x-referer
xs`

[Google Chrome with cookies of m.facebook.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nijcn.png)

but *getCookie()* method only return `dnonce`

Help would be appriciated.

**The scenario is I want to develop an Android app that has a single web view. When app starts I want to check if user is logged in with Facebook, if yes then redirect it to some *URL* otherwise open Facebook login page.
To check user successful login I came up with the logic to check `c_user` (unique user id) cookie but I can't get it via `getCookie` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cookie value using this

```
getCookie("http://www.example.com","cookieName");
```

Declare the function as

```
public String getCookie(String siteName,String cookieName){     
    String CookieValue = null;

    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName);       
    String[] temp=cookies.split(";");
    for (String ar1 : temp ){
        if(ar1.contains(cookieName)){
            String[] temp1=ar1.split("=");
            CookieValue = temp1[1];
            break;
        }
    }              
    return CookieValue; 
}
```

Try this class for all cookies. CookieManager with the java.net

```
import java.net.CookieHandler;
    import java.net.CookieManager;
    import java.net.CookiePolicy;
    import java.net.HttpCookie;
    import java.util.List;

    private class MyCookieManager
    {       
        private CookieManager mCookieManager = null;

        MyCookieManager() {
            mCookieManager = new CookieManager();
            mCookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
            CookieHandler.setDefault(mCookieManager);
        }

        private List<HttpCookie> getCookies() {
            if(mCookieManager == null)
                return null;
            else
                return mCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        }

        public void clearCookies() {
            if(mCookieManager != null)
                mCookieManager.getCookieStore().removeAll();
        } 

        public boolean isCookieManagerEmpty() {
            if(mCookieManager == null)
                return true;
            else 
                return mCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().isEmpty();
        }


        public String getCookieValue() {
            String cookieValue = new String();

            if(!isCookieManagerEmpty()) {
                for (HttpCookie eachCookie : getCookies())
                    cookieValue = cookieValue + String.format("%s=%s; ", eachCookie.getName(), eachCookie.getValue());
            }

            return cookieValue;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is I'm getting only single cookie `dnonce` in `String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(siteName);` where as I'm expecting more cookies as shown in Chrome browser.
Does browser store more cookies the webview in android?

Comment: @MuneebShafiq check class to get all cookies

Comment: @AnasMaher this function isn't returning even a single cookie!

Comment: @MuneebShafiq were u able to resolve the issue. I am also facing the one of the kind issue of cookies - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59611761/android-webview-webkit-cookiemanager-neglecting-cookie-attributes-like-expire. I am not getting the cookie attributes.

Comment: @RaghavSharma actually some websites don't allow cookies to be read! There's a flag in the header that restricts android to read all cookies! 
I was looking for the link I read that but couldn't find it! I'll share to you if I find it.
In short you can't read all attributes of cookies if site dosen't allow you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the the exact url to the `CookieManage getCookie` method. The url you load in `WebView loadUrl` method.
For example:

```
webview.loadUrl("https://m.facebook.com");
```

Then when you call the method for getting cookies.

```
getCookie("https://m.facebook.com");
```

And also import the correct CookieManager.

```
import android.webkit.CookieManager;

public String getCookie(String site) {
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(site);
    return cookies;
}
```